# Find rows with the same value in a column in two files

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I've got two files (millions of columns)

**File1.txt**, ~4k rows

```
some_key1 some_text1
some_key2 some_text2
...
some_keyn some_textn
```

**File2.txt**, ~20 M rows

```
some_key11 some_key11 some_text1
some_key22 some_key22 some_text2
...
some_keynn some_keynn some_textn
```

When there is an exact match between column 2 in `File1.txt` and column 3 in `File2.txt`, I want to print out the particular rows from both files.

**EDIT**

I've tried this (I forgot to write it) but it doesn't work

```
awk 'NR{a[$2]}==FNR{b[$3]}'$1 in a{print $1}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: And what you have done so far?

Comment: I've edited the question. I've forgot to add my try. @JoaoVitorino

Comment: Please be more specific on what matches to what. Is there only one column which should match? Why the files have the same names?

Comment: @liborm could be more than one row with the same column. 
File with same name is a typo.

Comment: And what about the number of rows? This is actually more important for the performance than the number of columns.

Comment: Do you wanna print in result.txt the commons "keys" in both files?

Comment: file1.txt is 4095 rows, file2.txt is 16592847 rows. @liborm

Comment: @JoaoVitorino Nope, the common some_text column. The key colums is different between two files.

Comment: What are you hoping the middle `'` in `'foo'bar'` would mean?

Comment: What? @EdMorton

Comment: You said you tried `awk 'NR{a[$2]}==FNR{b[$3]}'$1 in a{print $1}' ` which has 3 single quotes in it: `awk 'NR...}'$1...}'`. Obviously you can't have a [unescaped] character in the middle of a string or script that's delimited by that character so  - what were you hoping the single quote in the middle would mean? What you have is like writing an English sentence like `He said "here is"the answer" to me`. It doesn't make sense to have `"` in the middle of a `"`-delimited statement and that's true for any given character so what was your intent with the `'` mid-script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your dataset is big in both dimensions - rows and columns. Then you want to use `join`. To use `join`, you have to sort your data first. Something along those lines:

```
<File1.txt sort -k2,2 > File1-sorted.txt
<File2.txt sort -k3,3 -S1G > File2-sorted.txt

join -1 2 -2 3 File1-sorted.txt File2-sorted.txt > matches.txt
```

The `sort -k2,2` means 'sort whole rows so the values of second column are in ascending order. The `join -1 2` means 'the key in the first file is the second column'.

If your files are bigger than say 100 MB it pays of to assign additional memory to the `sort` via the `-S` option. The rule of thumb is to assign 1.3 times the size of the input to avoid any disk swapping by `sort`. But only if your system can handle that.

---

If one of your data files is very small (say up to 100 lines), you can consider doing something like

```
<File2.txt fgrep -F <( <File1.txt cut -f2 ) > File2-matches.txt
```

to avoid the `sort`, but then you'd have to look up the 'keys' from that file.

The decision which one to use is very similar to the 'hash join' and 'merge join' in the database world.

Comment: join: File1-sorted.txt:3: is not sorted: 00000001   9D1DD657B7ED0FFA... I don't know what does it mean

Comment: It means what it says;) The input files have to be sorted on the column you're using as the join key. I suppose that in your data it won't be the second and third columns, so you need to change the `-k2,2` and `-1 2` parts accordingly. And take care with the delimiters - if your fields have spaces in them, you need to use eg `\t`. (And - i just fixed a typo in the sample script.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your `awk` program

To print all records in file2 if field 1 (file1) exists in field 3 (file2):-

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$2];next}$3 in A' file1.txt file2.txt
some_key11 some_key11 some_text1
some_key22 some_key22 some_text2
...
some_keynn some_keynn some_textn
```

To print just field 1 in file2 if field 1 (file1) exists in field 3 (file2):-

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$2];next}$3 in A{ print $1 }' file1.txt file2.txt
some_key11
some_key22
...
some_keynn
```

Comment: The problem is a little bit different! I don't care if some keys exist in the other file*.txt. I want match the some_text field!